Am I able to include the score.py file as an artifact?
I am trying to deploy a very simple model:
import mlflow


class FunctionModel(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    
    def load_context(self,context):
        def rag_pipeline_function():
            from haystack import Pipeline, Document
            from haystack.utils import Secret
            #from haystack.utils.secret import Secret
            from haystack.document_stores.in_memory import InMemoryDocumentStore
            from haystack.components.retrievers.in_memory import InMemoryBM25Retriever
            from haystack.components.generators import OpenAIGenerator
            from haystack.components.builders.answer_builder import AnswerBuilder
            from haystack.components.builders.prompt_builder import PromptBuilder
                
            # Write documents to InMemoryDocumentStore
            document_store = InMemoryDocumentStore()
            document_store.write_documents([
          Document(content="My name is Jean and I live in Paris."), 
          Document(content="My name is Mark and I live in Berlin."), 
          Document(content="My name is Giorgio and I live in Rome.")
          ])

             # Build a RAG pipeline
            prompt_template = """
              Given these documents, answer the question.
              Documents:
              {% for doc in documents %}
              {{ doc.content }} 
              {% endfor %}
              Question: {{question}}
              Answer:
              """

            retriever = InMemoryBM25Retriever(document_store=document_store)
            prompt_builder = PromptBuilder(template=prompt_template)


            llm = OpenAIGenerator(api_key=Secret.from_token("myapi-key"))

            rag_pipeline = Pipeline()
            rag_pipeline.add_component("retriever", retriever)
            rag_pipeline.add_component("prompt_builder", prompt_builder)
            rag_pipeline.add_component("llm", llm)
            rag_pipeline.connect("retriever", "prompt_builder.documents")
            rag_pipeline.connect("prompt_builder", "llm")
            
            return rag_pipeline
        
        self.rag_pipeline = rag_pipeline_function()

    def predict(self, context, model_input):
        # Ensure model_input is a dictionary and extract the question
        if isinstance(model_input, dict) and "input_data" in model_input:
            question = model_input["input_data"]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input: 'input_data' key is missing or input is not a dictionary")

        # Run the RAG pipeline for the given input question
        results = self.rag_pipeline.run(
            {
                "retriever": {"query": question},
                "prompt_builder": {"question": question},
            }
        )
        return {"replies": results["llm"]["replies"]}

# Save the function as a model
with mlflow.start_run():
    model = FunctionModel()
    mlflow.pyfunc.log_model("model", python_model=model, pip_requirements=["haystack-ai"])
    run_id = mlflow.active_run().info.run_id

# Load the model for testing
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(f"runs:/{run_id}/model")

I ran this in Databricks, but when going to Serving I got an error that was something like 'model serving is not enabled on your shard..', so probably a region issue.
So, I took the artifacts of the run and went over to Azure ML Studio where I uploaded all the artifacts to register the model.
My aim is to deploy an endpoint, to atleast be able to utlise the Test tab for a demo, but it's telling me something is wrong with the scoring script - which I haven't got yet.
My question is can I create a score.py file and include it with the artifacts when registering the model? If so, what would this score.py look like for my model?

Yes you can create a scoring script and it's something like below.
But before that you need to have a model registered in workspace for deployment.
Register the model from the artifact local files

And your model path will be in the environment variable AZUREML_MODEL_DIR and use below scoring script accordingly.
import os
import logging
import json
import numpy
import joblib


def init():
    """
    This function is called when the container is initialized/started, typically after create/update of the deployment.
    You can write the logic here to perform init operations like caching the model in memory
    """
    global model
    # AZUREML_MODEL_DIR is an environment variable created during deployment.
    # It is the path to the model folder (./azureml-models/$MODEL_NAME/$VERSION)
    # Please provide your model's folder name if there is one
    model_path = os.path.join(
        os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "model/sklearn_regression_model.pkl"
    )
    # deserialize the model file back into a sklearn model
    model = joblib.load(model_path)
    logging.info("Init complete")


def run(raw_data):
    """
    This function is called for every invocation of the endpoint to perform the actual scoring/prediction.
    In the example we extract the data from the json input and call the scikit-learn model's predict()
    method and return the result back
    """
    logging.info("model 1: request received")
    data = json.loads(raw_data)["data"]
    data = numpy.array(data)
    result = model.predict(data)
    logging.info("Request processed")
    return result.tolist()

This script  loads the pickle model and takes list of data as input to predict and return the result as list.
In your case alter script according to your input and model output.
Try to use the mlflow model or pickle model to register and use it in deployment.
And use this code to configure deployment
also refer this sample code.
